# Command not found in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, command

I followed a tutorial to use command to build, run, ... in phonegap at http://docs.phonegap.com but I can't use those commands, except the `Create` command.
The `Create` command is:

```
create ./test1 com.test1 test1
the original command is: $ /path/to/cordova-android/bin/create.bat /path/to/my_new_cordova_project com.example.cordova_project_name CordovaProjectName
```

After created project successfully, I run the command:

```
cd test1/cordova/build
the original command is: $ /path/to/my_new_cordova_project/cordova/build.bat
```

but it throws an error:

> 'build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Then I go to my new project folder, go in folder: cordova to look for build.bat, but I see nothing.
Can you show me how to fix this stuff, i want to use command to build my phonegap project. Thanks!

Additional info:
Using phonegap 2.6, android platform.
Windows 7 64bit.
I'm able to run command: ant, java, javac, and some in the android platform tools,...